# Microsoft-IIS/6.0: Need php/mysql but only have access to ftp

Tags: iis, hosting, ftp, wordpress

I need to run php/mysql.

I want WordPress.

I only have ftp access on a server setup with IIS 6.

Is this possible? The website is hosted on Network Solutions. Do I need to reset the whole server?

Forgot to mention the server runs .net.

I dont want to take the whole site down while I setup a newer one

Noob question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server isn't already running IIS with PHP and MySql, you just can't set them up using only FTP.

FTP can only transfer files and do very minor shell commands, it certainly can't do the complicated setup required to install PHP & MySQl, let alone configure IIS.

You have to get remote desktop access.

Comment: Thank you, sire. Need to see if I can have the permissions to obtain remote access